# Some bug within parallel Red/Black Successive Over Relaxation(SOR) implementation

Tags: c, mpi, parallel-processing

One of my assignment is to implement RED/BLACK SOR algorithm using MPI. The grid is divided as checkboard and each iteration is split into two phases red and black. During each phase algorithm calculates either red or black non-boundary points of the grid. Rest of implementation is similar to as define in [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Successive_over-relaxation#Algorithm).

Full Code: sequential [here](http://pastebin.com/wgk74RAm), parallel [here](http://pastebin.com/WUieKtuT).

Here is the sequential implementation

```
iteration = 0;
do {
    maxdiff = 0.0;
    for ( phase = 0; phase < 2 ; phase++){
        for ( i = 1 ; i < N-1 ; i++ ){
            for ( j = 1 + (even(i) ^ phase); j < N-1 ; j += 2 ){
                Gnew = stencil(G,i,j);
                diff = fabs(Gnew - G[i][j]);
                if ( diff > maxdiff )
                    maxdiff = diff;
                G[i][j] = G[i][j] + omega * (Gnew-G[i][j]);
            }
        }
    }
    iteration++;
} while (maxdiff > stopdiff);
```

For parallel implementation grid is first divided equally for different nodes (column wise).
For example, if grid size is 8x8 and nodes 3, then we divide grid as 8x3, 8x3, 8x2 across those nodes.
During communication data are exchanged to and from node's left and right neighbors. Figure below should give a clear picture of entire process.

```
/* Initializing MPI */
MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &totalnodes);
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &mynode);

// divide grid equally among different nodes
range(1, N - 1, totalnodes, mynode, &jsta, &jend);

// neigboring nodes
inext = mynode + 1;
iprev = mynode - 1;

iteration = 0;
do {
    maxdiff = 0.0;
    for ( phase = 0; phase < 2 ; phase++){

        // exchange column with neigboring node
        exchange(phase);

        for ( i = 1 ; i < N-1 ; i++ ){          // row

            for ( j = jsta + (even(i) ^ phase); j <= jend ; j += 2 ){   // column

                Gnew = stencil(G,i,j);
                diff = fabs(Gnew - G[i][j]);
                if ( diff > maxdiff )
                    maxdiff = diff;
                G[i][j] = G[i][j] + omega * (Gnew-G[i][j]);
            }
        }
    }

    MPI_Allreduce(&maxdiff, &diff, 1, MPI_DOUBLE, MPI_MAX, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    maxdiff = diff;

    iteration++;
} while (maxdiff > stopdiff);

MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
MPI_Finalize();
```

Figure describes how grid is divided and neighbors communicate.
[image: Figure describes how grid is divided and neighbors communicate.]

Problem is, final result of parallel and sequential SOR seem to vary by few bits.
Need a fresh pair eye to skim through code to track this bug, I think communication between nodes are working alright.

```
$ cc -o sor-seq sor-seq.c -lm      
$ ./sor-seq 8 -print
    Running 8 x 8 SOR
    6.006      5.525      5.330      5.251      5.234      5.276      5.417      5.799 
    6.621      6.204      5.984      5.879      5.850      5.892      6.032      6.338 
    6.952      6.687      6.523      6.432      6.395      6.409      6.483      6.640 
    7.181      7.069      6.988      6.931      6.891      6.864      6.852      6.857 
    7.382      7.420      7.429      7.414      7.373      7.306      7.203      7.059 
    7.607      7.799      7.896      7.920      7.884      7.782      7.595      7.294 
    7.926      8.273      8.436      8.488      8.459      8.344      8.101      7.643 
    8.506      8.929      9.088      9.136      9.120      9.033      8.821      8.298 


$ mpicc -o sor-par sor-par.c   
$ mpirun -n 3 ./sor-seq 8 -print
    Running 8 x 8 SOR
    5.940      5.383      5.092      4.882      4.677      4.425      4.072      3.507
    6.496      5.939      5.542      5.201      4.839      4.392      3.794      2.950
    6.786      6.334      5.938      5.542      5.086      4.512      3.761      2.773
    6.994      6.672      6.334      5.942      5.450      4.809      3.964      2.873
    7.197      7.028      6.784      6.442      5.965      5.308      4.414      3.228
    7.445      7.457      7.335      7.075      6.660      6.045      5.157      3.896
    7.807      8.020      8.022      7.864      7.555      7.055      6.273      5.032
    8.443      8.795      8.868      8.805      8.640      8.348      7.848      6.920

    Node: 0
         5.940      5.383      5.092      4.882      0.000      0.000      0.000      0.000 
         6.496      5.939      5.542      5.201      0.000      0.000      0.000      0.000 
         6.786      6.334      5.938      5.542      0.000      0.000      0.000      0.000 
         6.994      6.672      6.334      5.942      0.000      0.000      0.000      0.000 
         7.197      7.028      6.784      6.442      0.000      0.000      0.000      0.000 
         7.445      7.457      7.335      7.075      0.000      0.000      0.000      0.000 
         7.807      8.020      8.022      7.864      0.000      0.000      0.000      0.000 
         8.443      8.795      8.868      8.805      0.000      0.000      0.000      0.000 

    Node: 1
         0.000      0.000      5.092      4.882      4.677      4.425      4.072      0.000 
         0.000      0.000      5.542      5.201      4.839      4.392      3.794      0.000 
         0.000      0.000      5.938      5.542      5.086      4.512      3.761      0.000 
         0.000      0.000      6.334      5.942      5.450      4.809      3.964      0.000 
         0.000      0.000      6.784      6.442      5.965      5.308      4.414      0.000 
         0.000      0.000      7.335      7.075      6.660      6.045      5.157      0.000 
         0.000      0.000      8.022      7.864      7.555      7.055      6.273      0.000 
         0.000      0.000      8.868      8.806      8.640      8.348      7.848      0.000 

    Node: 2
         0.000      0.000      0.000      0.000      0.000      4.425      4.072      3.507 
         0.000      0.000      0.000      0.000      0.000      4.392      3.794      2.950 
         0.000      0.000      0.000      0.000      0.000      4.512      3.761      2.773 
         0.000      0.000      0.000      0.000      0.000      4.809      3.964      2.873 
         0.000      0.000      0.000      0.000      0.000      5.308      4.414      3.228 
         0.000      0.000      0.000      0.000      0.000      6.045      5.157      3.896 
         0.000      0.000      0.000      0.000      0.000      7.055      6.273      5.032 
         0.000      0.000      0.000      0.000      0.000      8.348      7.848      6.920
```

Comment: It's not a question, it's a dissertation! :)

Comment: I have been working on this for days without result, will try to reduce it :)

Comment: You do know that with floating points you aren't guaranteed to reproduce results exactly?

Comment: The number of iterations is not the same for the sequential and parallel versions. There is some problem in the communication. My guess is that your code is recalculating the edge columns for 2 sequential nodes. That is 3rd column grid values are calculated by both Node 0 and Node 1. You can check that once. Also, you might want to consider using MPI_SendRecv() instead of two async sends and receives. Not that it will affect your output, but it will make your code "cleaner".

Comment: The actual calculation part looks fine. The only change in your sequential and parallel versions is the communication. So you should focus on that. And float values don't give the exact same results under certain conditions, but your problem does not qualify for this eccentricity. So you should get the exact same grid values in both the sequential and parallel versions up to at least 6 decimal places for floats and 12 decimal places for double.

Comment: hummm...okay will do some more work inside data exchanging part. One of my buddy suggested that may be grid should be divided in terms of rows and not columns, would that make any difference? Oh I wish there were better debugging tool for MPI other than printf(), thanx & appreciate lot for all the help :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought of trying a debugger on it?  I am *very* biased as I work for an MPI debugger company, but I just downloaded your code, and tried it in Allinea DDT, and it stopped in stencil() when it detected a read beyond the end of your array, initially by process 7.

To reproduce this, compile your code with "-g" for debugging support, and get hold of Allinea DDT from http://www.allinea.com, install it, and turn on Memory Debugging (and ensure you have "Guard Pages" configured Above, with 1 Page in the Memory Debugging settings).

Run your program, with, say, 8 processes, and you should soon find your answer, in seconds.

Good luck!

David

Comment: I downloaded and installed ddt (http://content.allinea.com/downloads/ddt3.1-20638-Ubuntu-10.04-x86_64.tar), upon trying to run it I got /opt/allinea/ddt/libexec/ddt-splash: 1: Syntax error: ")" unexpected. I am not sure if I executed it correctly, didn't find any forum on allinea.com
$ /opt/allinea/ddt/bin/ddt mpirun -n 3 ./sor-par 8 -print

Comment: Aman - you probably downloaded the wrong architecture - eg. if your machine is 32-bit you need the 32-bit binaries - I think you've tried a 64 bit binary there.

Answer (score 0):

This looks suspect:

```
MPI_Isend(bufs1, icnt1, MPI_DOUBLE, iprev, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &ireqs1);
MPI_Isend(bufs2, icnt2, MPI_DOUBLE, inext, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &ireqs2);

MPI_Irecv(bufr1, N, MPI_DOUBLE, iprev, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &ireqr1);
MPI_Irecv(bufr2, N, MPI_DOUBLE, inext, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &ireqr2);

MPI_Wait(&ireqs1, &istatus);
MPI_Wait(&ireqs2, &istatus);
MPI_Wait(&ireqr1, &istatus);
MPI_Wait(&ireqr2, &istatus);
```

I would have expected something like:

```
MPI_Isend(bufs1, icnt1, MPI_DOUBLE, iprev, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &ireqs1);
MPI_Isend(bufs2, icnt2, MPI_DOUBLE, inext, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &ireqs2);

MPI_Wait(&ireqs1, &istatus);
MPI_Wait(&ireqs2, &istatus);

MPI_Irecv(bufr1, N, MPI_DOUBLE, iprev, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &ireqr1);
MPI_Irecv(bufr2, N, MPI_DOUBLE, inext, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &ireqr2);

MPI_Wait(&ireqs1, &istatus);
MPI_Wait(&ireqs2, &istatus);
```

And possibly the middle two wait()s are not needed at all.

Comment: i tried your way, it didn't seem to make any difference in final result